# node.js setTimeout *sometimes* wakes up much later than expected

Tags: node.js, settimeout

I have a nodejs program that runs, mostly normally. It does it's thing, then sleeps for a while, then wakes up and does it again. This is pretty reliable.

It also does some logging, so I can watch the progress and status:

```
[2013-Dec-03 08:01:13] setWakeup
[2013-Dec-03 08:01:13] job4 55 runs per hour
[2013-Dec-03 08:01:13] job4 sleep 59962ms, wake at 08:02:13
[2013-Dec-03 08:02:13] job4 awake
 ....
```

When it logs "sleep", really it is calling setTimeout() with the quantity of ms indicated. Notice the "awake" message appears to be about 60 seconds after the "sleep" message, according to the timestamp.

### The problem is...

Sometimes this setTimeout does not wake up at the expected time.  I'm not talking about missing by a few milliseconds, or even a few percent. I'm saying that sometimes I want it to sleep for 60 seconds, and it sleeps for 45 minutes. Check this out.

```
[2013-Dec-03 07:16:11] setWakeup
[2013-Dec-03 07:16:11] job4 54 runs per hour
[2013-Dec-03 07:16:11] job4 sleep 61297ms, wake at 07:17:12
[2013-Dec-03 08:01:08] job4 awake
 ....
```

Notice the "awake" message has a timestamp roughly 45 minutes after the sleep message. 
This is on a MacBook Pro, node v0.10.22 .
Is it possible the computer has gone to sleep? How can I get it to wake up reliably, within a few percent of the setTimeout() quantity?

Comment: As a side note: `setTimeout()` adds an event on the event loop, which isn't guaranteed to fire exactly when you want, see [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout#Minimum.2F_maximum_delay_and_timeout_nesting).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your Mac indeed went to sleep.

You can use `pmset` (a CLI tool) to set the wake up time. Looking at the manual page (`man pmset`), this might work from Node:

```
var child_process = require('child_process');

// to set a specific wake up time:
child_process.spawn('pmset', [ 'schedule', 'wake', 'time', 'HH:MM:SS' ]);
```

(where `HH:MM:SS` are hours/minutes/seconds clocktime at which you want it to wake).

However, I'm not sure if you can get it to wake up reliably enough to reach that 'within a few percent'.

I'm also not familiar enough with the inner workings of `setTimeout` to know if your Mac falling asleep might interfere with it (as it basically stops the Node process).